# Multithreading function takes exactly 6 arguments (0 given) error

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

i have created simple threading function but i am getting error that 0 arguments are passed even though I have passed all 6 arguments. I have tried both using args and kwargs and still I have having same error

below is my code

```
import time
import datetime
import threading

def get_time():
    datestart = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes = 60)
    dateend = datetime.datetime.now()
    timeprevious = int(time.mktime(datestart.timetuple()) * 1000)
    timenow = int(time.mktime(dateend.timetuple()) * 1000)
    return timeprevious, timenow

def customer(src_ip,dst_ip,host_ip,index_name,timeprevious,timenow):
  print(src_ip)
  print(dst_ip)
  print(host_ip)
  print(index_name)
  print(timeprevious)
  print(timenow)

host_name = ['host_name1', 'host_name2', 'host_name3']
host_ip = ['host_ip1', 'host_ip2', 'host_ip3']
index_name = ['index_name1',' index_name2', 'index_name3']
src_ip = ['Src_IP', 'source_ip', 'SourceAddress']
dst_ip = ['Dst_IP', 'destination_ip', 'DestinationAddress']

timeprevious, timenow = get_time()

threads = []                                                                
for i in range(len(host_name)):
  try:
    # t = threading.Thread(target=customer(), args=(src_ip[i],dst_ip[i],host_ip[i],index_name[i],timeprevious,timenow))
    t = threading.Thread(target=customer(), kwargs={'src_ip': src_ip[i],'dst_ip':dst_ip[i],'host_ip': host_ip[i],'index_name': index_name[i],'timeprevious': timeprevious,'timenow': timenow })

    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
  except Exception as e:
    print('error ' + host_name[i])
    print(e)

for t in threads:                                                           
  t.join()
```

This is the error I am having 
`customer() takes exactly 6 arguments (0 given)`. You can see in the comment that I have also used kwargs to solve the error still I am having no luck. Also is this the correct way to pass multiple arguments?

Comment: It should be `target=customer` (a function object taking 6 arguments), not `target=customer()` (which is `None`).

Comment: @CedricH.Thank you very much for your quick response. it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue on the following line:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=customer(), kwargs={'src_ip': src_ip[i],'dst_ip':dst_ip[i],'host_ip': host_ip[i],'index_name': index_name[i],'timeprevious': timeprevious,'timenow': timenow })*emphasized text*
```

`target=customer()` sets the value of the target function to the return value of calling `customer()`. To pass a reference to the customer function use `target=customer`